# Redirect C output to a txt file

Tags: c, io-redirection

I am redirecting program output to a txt file and entering the values prompted by the main function:
[image: terminal capture]

I expected my output.txt file to have the following data:

```
Enter float1: 2.4
Enter float1: 4.6
```

But instead, it has this:

```
Enter float1: 
Enter float1:
```

Here is my main function:

```
printf("Enter float1: ");
scanf("%f", &float1);
printf("Enter float2: ");
scanf("%f", &float2);
```

Can anyone please help to redirect inputted values as well?
I researched the question but I couldn't find anything that would solve the problem.
I tried redirection stderr to see if the values are printed there but it gave me an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user input is `stdin` but you are redirecting only `stdout` to file. Hence you will see in the `output.txt` only what your program prints to `stdout`. If you want to print entered values, you have to print them after `scanf`.

In the example below, you should see also input values in your `output.txt`

```
printf("Enter float1: ");
scanf("%f", &float1);
printf("%f\n", float1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the two values with `scanf()` but you didn't print them (with `printf()` for example), so they don't appear in `stdout`.

When we input something on the standard input with the keyboard, we can see the text just because the *terminal* (not your program) echoes these characters.
So, redirecting your program's standard output does not change anything to that.

Answer (score 1):

Change your main to:

```
printf("Enter float1: ");
scanf("%f", &float1);
printf("%f\n", float1);
printf("Enter float2: ");
scanf("%f", &float2);
printf("%f\n", float2);
```

On a side note, if you're confused about redirection, `printf` is a modified version of `fprintf`. Printing to the console is just so common there's a function for it. Saying `printf("%f\n", float1)` is the same as `fprintf(stdout, "%f\n", float1)`. Same goes for `scanf` vs. `fscanf`. Redirecting output allows you to keep your `printf` statements in your code, yet still print to a file. Else you would have manually change them all to `fprintf` which would be  a pain.